# MySQL Workbench 8.0.28 hangs on launch (Window 10 Pro)

Tags: mysql, windows, workbench

I have been using MySQL workbench for years. Recently the previous version 8.0.nnn stopped launching. I decided to try to repair the installation by upgrading. It worked for a few days and now it hangs again.

Uninstalling and reinstalling is not helping.

There are no notifications in event viewer. There is a task (process) in Task Viewer, but the process does not progress to showing a window.

I can connect to, and query, the server on the command line or via the API (not that it is required for launching Workbench).

Any ideas about origin of this rather perplexing problem?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the user data (User\AppData\Roaming\MysSQL\Workbench) contained corrupted files.
The error message popup (window) remains hidden, but can be seen when using Alt-Tab to rotate between applications. One cannot bring focus on the error window, but one can see the message among the choices in the Alt-Tab interface. I could see something about corrupt file and that it was in the profile's Roaming.

Deletion of the single file that was indicated (wb_state.xml) was insufficient to get WorkBench to display. Deletion of all files in the Workbench directory restored Workbench.

Hope this is of some use to others.